# Table Cell Drop down menu anchored to the right of cell

Tags: html, css

I have a basic table with a div contained in it that I bring out of the cell "position: absolute" and it comes up nicely below the table cell starting at the left of the cell and flowing to the right.

I want to be able to do this backwards with the last cell (that is have the submenu table anchor itself to the right of the cell(or essentially the table)

I've got this working in FireFox, (bit mess) but it doesn't work in IE.

The Html is as follows

```
<table style="background-color: gold;" border="1" bordercolor="orange"  cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <th>Parent Cell 1
        <div style="position: absolute;  background-color: green; color: white;">
            supercalifragilisticexpialidocious
        </div>
        </th>
        <th>Parent Cell 2
        </th>
        <th>Parent Cell 3
        </th>
        <th>Parent Cell 4
        </th>
        <th>Parent Cell 5
            <div style="float:right; ">
                <div style="position:absolute;">
                    <div style="position: absolute; right: 0px; background-color: green; color: white;">
                        supercalifragilisticexpialidocious
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Does anyone know how I could get the the rightmost submenu item (in a sense) to drop down to the same level as the left one. As I said this (simplified version) works in FireFox, just not in IE and I need it to work in both... :S

I also don't know if the rightmost cell is structured in the most appropriate way or whether there is a better way!

Thanks

Comment: Is this going to be used to build a menu? If so, use `<ul>` and `<li>` instead. Also use a nested `<ul>` for your submenu. Floating probably isn't necessary, using a `right` offset should do the trick.

Comment: The idea is to have a drop down menu from a table cell. The right most column would have a drop down menu that is anchored to the right of that cell (thus avoiding some or more horizontal scroll)

Comment: With <ul> and <li> i still have the same issue of getting the content to possition itself to the right of the parent cell (Table cell) The float right is so that the child div's absolute position will be to the right of the table cell and so that i can us a right offset relative to the parent div instead of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, from what I gather this is basically what you want, except I've done it using semantic markup and CSS.

**The Markup**

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li>
        <a href="#">Parent 1</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Child Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Child Item 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Child Item 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Child Item 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Parent 2</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Parent 3</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Child Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Child Item 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Child Item 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Child Item 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**The CSS**

```
#nav {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    height: 20px;
}
#nav li {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 150px;
    height: 20px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    background: #eee;
}
#nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 130px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 21px;
    left: 0;
    list-style: none;
    display: none;
}
#nav li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
#nav ul li {
    width: auto;
    float: none;
}
```

If you want the child lists anchored to the right then you would change the CSS declaration under `#nav ul` that reads `left: 0;` to read `right: 0;` instead.

This will work in IE7+. For IE6 you will need to use a script based solution to get the hover going, such as [whatever:hover](http://www.xs4all.nl/~peterned/csshover.html), or write your own if that's too heavy-handed for your liking.

Comment: Thanks Jason. Thank you very much for taking the time with this. 
It's a very nice and neat example...
Works in IE 8 also which is nice.
The right align also works really nicely!

I'll just use one parent item inside the table cell and it might work fine!

Cheerz!
Cheerz!